# Well order of naturals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

I have an exercise that asks me for 15 non-isomorphic well order types of natural numbers, I have some, can you help me with other well uncommon orders?

Thank you

Comment: Suggest you put in question which well orders you already found. This will show you did some work on it, which the site usually wants to see or they put questions "on hold".

Comment: I hate to say this ordering them so that $a < b$ if the either the remainder of $a$ when divided by $k$ is less than $b$'s remainder or if their remainders are the same if $a$ is smaller than $b$ in the usual order; you can do that for $15$ different values of $k$.  They aren't isomorphic but that really seems to defeat the spirit of the question.

Comment: Take as many countable well-orders as you like, from the countable ordinals. $\omega,\omega+1, \ldots, \omega + 14$ are already $15$ different ones. Transport them to the natural numbers via a bijection.

Comment: 15 is a joke... I know uncountably many :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\omega_0$ + n for all n in N are equinumerous to N
well ordered and not pairwise order isomorphic.
1,2,3,... 0;  2,3,4,... 0,1;  and so on.

$\omega_0$ + $\omega_0$ + n is yet another bunch of examples.
For example placing all of the even numbers in order before all of the odd numbers in order.  0,2,3,... 1,3,5,...

This idea can be continued indefinitely
0,3,6,... 1,4,7,... 2,5.8,... 
and so forth for other sets of integers modulus n.

But wait, there are scads more based upon even larger ordinals such as $\omega_0 × \omega_0$.   Here's a small wow
0 2 5 ...
1 4 ...
3 ...
•••

For bigger wows, go for higher powers of $\omega_0$.
Beyond all of those are colossal wowies.